# Adding COUNT together when grouping twice SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, cross-apply

I currently have these results:

```
 SELECT P.[PersonID], P.PersonName AS [Name], MIN(P.Team) AS [Team], 
 COUNT( DISTINCT C.CustomerName) AS [Number Of Customers],
 SUM(F.Amount) AS [Amount]
 FROM Person P
 JOIN Figure F on P.PersonID =F.PersonFK
 JOIN Customer C ON C.CustomerFK = F.FigureID

 GROUP BY P.[PersonID],P.PersonName
 order by P.[PersonID]
```

Results:

```
PersonID    Name    Team    Number Of Customers    Daily Amount
   1        Ben      1              3                  30
   2        Sam      2              2                  30
   3        Tom      2              3                  30
   4        Fred     3              3                  30
   5        Alex     4              3                  30
```

Now im using a cross apply to further group people who fall under team 2

code:

```
SELECT Z.[Person], MIN(P.Team) AS [Team], 
COUNT( DISTINCT C.CustomerName) AS [Number Of Customers],
SUM(F.Amount) AS [Amount]
FROM Person P
JOIN Figure F on P.PersonID =F.PersonFK
JOIN Customer C ON C.CustomerFK = F.FigureID

   cross apply (values
   (case when p.[Team] = '2' then 'Team 2'
   ELSE p.PersonName
   END)
   ) AS Z ([Person])

GROUP BY Z.[Person]
order by Z.[Person]
```

Result:

```
 Person   Team    Number Of Customers      Daily Amount 
 Alex      4               3                   30   
 Ben       1               3                   30   
 Fred      3               3                   30   
 Team 2    2               3                   60
```

However, how can i sum together the count for the team 2

e.g.

```
 Team 2    2               5                   60
```

I know that this column has to be summed together but how can i do this without messing with the other counts? so far i cant find anyway. Can anyone help? thanks

SQL FIDDLE - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/546b0/10

Comment: No, the number of customers is a distinct count.  So the code is working corectly.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i understand, but is there anyway i can get the result i am looking for. adding together the count with the cross apply?

Comment: . . I answered the question.  My comment is more to the structure of your query.  You seem to want a distinct count so it is not obvious that the value is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working correctly, because you are are asking for distinct customers. If you want distinct customer/person pairs, then you need to write the logic for that:

```
select z.[Person], min(p.Team) AS [Team], 
       count(distinct p.PersonName + ':' + C.CustomerName) as [Number Of Customers],
       sum(f.Amount) AS [Amount]
from Person p join
     Figure f
     on P.PersonID = F.PersonFK join
     Customer C 
     on C.CustomerFK = F.FigureID cross apply 
     (values (case when p.[Team] = '2' then 'Team 2' else p.PersonName end)
     ) z (Person)
group by z.[Person]
order by z.[Person] ;
```

It would be nice is SQL Server supported multiple arguments to `COUNT(DISTINCT)` -- as some other databases do.  Concatenating the strings together should do what you want.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/546b0/12) is the SQL Fiddle.